# Is there anyway to include escape characters in a postman json request?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postman

I have a form that I am submitting. The form has fields which are encrypted and would be submitted through an API(Ruby on Rails backend). For testing purposes I am using postman to send the request.

The following is a sample of some of the code for the request.
`"nonce":"J9\xD5b\xFFe6'L\x1D\xB5\xF9", "tag":"\x9C\xA9\xAF\xC7\x03\xD2\xD0z\x10\xCE[\x970^\xB1V"`
Postman here shows an error `Invalid escape character in string` which is a result of json escape characters. The solution is to replace `\` with `\\` which results in the following
`nonce = J9\\xD5b\\xFFe6'L\\x1D\\xB5\\xF9`
and once I try and decrypt it, it obviously gives a key size error due to extended characters.
A very simple solution would be to add characters and then manually replace these in the params once received. Is there a better solution to this?